# Starting https Jenkins server on 127.0.0.1

Tags: jenkins

Embarrassingly enough I am one page into *Jenkins Continuous Integration Cookbook* and I'm already stuck on this command:

```
Java -jar jenkins.war --httpsPort=8443 --httpPort=-1
```

On my Mac, this throws up with:

```
Running from: /home/NAThompson/jenkins/war/target/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Feb 22, 2015 7:37:24 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Using one-time self-signed certificate
Feb 22, 2015 7:37:24 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
Feb 22, 2015 7:37:24 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start a listener: winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory
    at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:209)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:149)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at Main._main(Main.java:293)
    at Main.main(Main.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/x509/CertAndKeyGen
    at winstone.HttpsConnectorFactory.start(HttpsConnectorFactory.java:100)
    at winstone.Launcher.spawnListener(Launcher.java:207)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

What can I do to get around this? As extraneous info, the server starts just fine using `http`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would not recommend running Jenkins within a Mac environment unless of course you are developing for the Mac/IOS. In that case, you have an error with Java installation and/or configs. The real error is `ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen`. You should verify your version of Java with the requirements of the version of Jenkins you are using. I read a few blog articles that hinted that it is likely a discrepancy with the Java version you (Mac OS) is running.

Secondly, it is highly unlikely that you will ever use Mac for your CI needs. You should really look into running local virtual machines that will mimic your CI environments. You can get started easily with open source tools like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) and [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com).

Comment: The Mac is perfectly suited to run Jenkins.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a [known issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25333) with trying to use HTTPS directly from the jenkins.war. Some have suggested running Jenkins from within Tomcat and letting Tomcat handle SSL (I've not tried this personally yet, however).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue for myself by setting Jenkins to run using Java 7.  I am running it as a service so I did this by editing the jenkins-runner.sh file.  I added the following line:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

and then modified the last two lines to:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $javaArgs -jar "$war" $args
exec $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $javaArgs -jar "$war" $args
```

I also made sure to set the httpsKeyStore and httpsKeyStorePassword properties after creating a selfsigned certificate (instructions here under Using SSL: [Installing and Configuring Jenkins](https://wiki.wocommunity.org/display/documentation/Installing+and+Configuring+Jenkins))